# How to Create an Amazon API Gateway with a HTTP Integration using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create an AWS API gateway using cloud formation yaml template which integrate with HTTP function but could not succeed.

Anyone having experience on this please help.

Snippets i am using:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: AWS API Gateway with a HTTP Integration

Resources:

  ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      ApiKeySourceType: HEADER
      Description: An API Gateway with a HTTP Integration
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - EDGE
      Name: HTTP-api

  ApiGatewayResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: 'HTTP'
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi

  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: POST
      Integration:
        ConnectionType: INTERNET
        IntegrationResponses:
           Uri: !Sub 'http://www.msn.com/'
        Type: HTTP
        TimeoutInMillis: 29000
      MethodResponses:
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: !Ref ApiGatewayModel
          StatusCode: 200
        - ResponseModels:
            application/json: !Ref ApiGatewayModel
          StatusCode: 500
      OperationName: 'HTTP'
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiGatewayResource
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi

  ApiGatewayModel:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Model
    Properties:
      ContentType: 'application/json'
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      Schema: {}

  ApiGatewayStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref ApiGatewayDeployment
      Description: HTTP API Stage v0
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
      StageName: 'v0'

  ApiGatewayDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn: ApiGatewayMethod
    Properties:
      Description: HTTP API Deployment
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
```

Thanks,
Sanjeev

Comment: `with HTTP function`  do you mean Lambda function or pure http backend?

Comment: Hi - Pure HTTP function. Thanks,

Comment: One more - ` but could not succeed` could you be more elaborate? Please post what you have and and what are you missing..

Comment: added a snippet please check